# Android Virtual Device not installing

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to create an Android Virtual device, but I can't get past the System image selection. I select one, it starts installing, but when it's just almost finishing, it fails, printing out that it could not be installed.

I'm on a dual boot system (Kali Linux and Windows 10). Both Android Studio installations behave this way.

What could be the problem? I have HAXM installed and Virtualization enabled.

**UPDATE**

The following is part of the log in **idea.log**  *(/home/user/.AndroidStudio2.3/system/log/idea.log)*

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sources-23_r01.zip': Read timed out
, response: 200 OK
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.saveToFile(HttpRequests.java:345)
    at com.intellij.util.io.RequestBuilder.lambda$saveToFile$1(RequestBuilder.java:64)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.doProcess(HttpRequests.java:389)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.process(HttpRequests.java:383)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$100(HttpRequests.java:56)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestBuilderImpl.connect(HttpRequests.java:244)
    at com.intellij.util.io.RequestBuilder.saveToFile(RequestBuilder.java:64)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.StudioDownloader.downloadFully(StudioDownloader.java:86)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.BasicInstaller.doPrepare(BasicInstaller.java:71)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.prepare(AbstractPackageOperation.java:243)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.preparePackages(InstallTask.java:191)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.run(InstallTask.java:98)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:635)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$3.run(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:494)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:443)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:155)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:128)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:593)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:532)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3336)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3329)
    at com.intellij.util.net.NetUtils.copyStreamContent(NetUtils.java:191)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.saveToFile(HttpRequests.java:341)
    ... 24 more



2017-06-09 12:07:05,078 [2497208]   WARN - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml': Remote host closed connection during handshake 
2017-06-09 12:07:05,079 [2497209]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading file:/opt/android-studio/plugins/sdk-updates/offline-repo/offline-repo.xml 
2017-06-09 12:07:05,098 [2497228]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img2-1.xml 
2017-06-09 12:08:41,921 [2594051]   WARN - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img2-1.xml': Read timed out 
2017-06-09 12:08:41,922 [2594052]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img2-1.xml 
2017-06-09 12:09:01,937 [2614067]   WARN - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img2-1.xml': connect timed out 
2017-06-09 12:09:01,938 [2614068]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img2-1.xml 
2017-06-09 12:09:41,972 [2654102]   WARN - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img2-1.xml': dl.google.com 
2017-06-09 12:09:41,973 [2654103]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img2-1.xml 
2017-06-09 12:09:41,974 [2654104]   WARN - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img2-1.xml': dl.google.com 
2017-06-09 12:09:41,978 [2654108]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/sys-img2-1.xml 
2017-06-09 12:09:41,980 [2654110]   WARN - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/sys-img2-1.xml': dl.google.com 
2017-06-09 12:09:41,981 [2654111]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon2-1.xml 
2017-06-09 12:09:41,983 [2654113]   WARN - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon2-1.xml': dl.google.com 
2017-06-09 12:09:41,985 [2654115]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon2-1.xml 
2017-06-09 12:09:41,991 [2654121]   WARN - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon2-1.xml': dl.google.com 
2017-06-09 12:09:42,000 [2654130]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon2-1.xml 
2017-06-09 12:09:42,005 [2654135]   WARN - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon2-1.xml': dl.google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

verify the following and post some more information of the situation if they don't work.
1. first and foremost, you need to be connected to the internet.
2. have enough data( those AVD files are quite heavy averages 800MB per system)
3. suggest uninstalling what you have presently and reinstalling it afresh.

suggest having a look at this [Create and Manage Virtual Devices](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html).
need some more information if this doesn't help.
I'm from an african context and internet connection and data was my main road block for months without me knowing.